# Can terraform destroy/change state of resources that are not created by itself?

Tags: terraform

I have pre-existing VMs in vmware vsphere that I would like to delete and/or rename. I see that terraform is capable of creating and destroying resources that are created by terraform itself by checking the statefiles.
Is this possible to operate on other non-terraform created resources?

Comment: create a test VM normally and try it out. After that, share your new made experiences with us.

Comment: You can use `terraform import` to create a state from pre-existing resources.

Comment: @MattSchuchard if you can flesh that out that would make a good answer.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, thanks for pointing this out. Can I get an example too if possible for removing existing VM and Datastore resources?

Comment: @buttercup: As observed with tests, If we want to operate on existing resources, we can import them and then further operate on them because we get the state of those resources.